# Print a div without opening up a new Window in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to print the contents of a `div` using a `button`. I have searched it and found the way out, to do it in AngularJS.

My issue is whenever print is invoked, it also opens up a new window; it shouldn't open it up.

Is there a way to block the opening of the new window?

Code below:

**JS:**

```
$scope.printControl = function(id) {
    var printContents = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
    var popupWin = $window.open('', '_blank', 'width=800,height=800');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</body></html>');
    popupWin.document.close();
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="printDiv">
    This div needs to be printed
  </div>
  <button ng-click="printControl('printDiv')">
  Print
</button>
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/nomp0ee8/)

Comment: Well you actually have defined in your JS to open a new window ($window.open('', '_blank'...). You can replace "_blank" with "_self". This will open the print prompt int he same window without navigating away from there. But I believe you cannot actually disgard this prompt at all as the user has to have the last control over the printing itself for safety reasons.

Comment: @Martin on doing this, I am able to see the `div` contents in the window itself, which I do not want.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do:

```
$scope.printControl = function(id) {
   $scope.visible = true;
   $timeout(function(){
        $window.print();         
        $timeout(function(){
           $scope.visible = false;
        }, 0);
   }, 0);
};
```

and modify your button this way:

```
<button ng-click="printControl('printDiv')" ng-hide="visible">
```

the idea is to hide the elements you don't want to print in your dom when you click the button to print, and re-show them immediately after.

link to updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/62gpa2wy/).

Comment: The whole `html` is getting printed. Only `div` should get printed.

Comment: i'm afraid that that's the only way to do it without opening a new window istance, let's hope in another solution though.